# Unable to access Kurento media server running on Docker via localhost

Tags: windows, docker, kurento

I am trying to set up a Kurento media server using docker, running on a Windows 10 Enterprise server. I wish to use it to convert a RTSP stream into a web-usable video stream. I have pulled the kurento package and am able to run the image as a container, however, I cannot connect to the container locally.

I have tried port mapping to ports 8888, 8443, and various others, and both 6.9.0 and 6.10.0 KMS versions to no avail.

Here's a copy of the log file:
https://pastebin.com/SnAU5mA7

The line that worries me the most is this, but I'm unsure of its implications:

`0:00:00.984297800     1 0x55991fde20d0 INFO    KurentoWebSocketTransport WebSocketTransport.cpp:216:WebSocketTransport: Secure websocket server not enabled`

Additionally, the container also shows as 'unhealthy' when spun up, however, I am relatively sure that this is due to powershell not having the linux version of curl installed, which the healthchecker uses to check the container status. I have tried running the image with and without the --no-healthcheck option; neither works.

Comment: Can you add your `docker run` command?

Comment: I've tried serveral different run commands, as mentioned, with both differing ports and no-healthcheck both on and off.
`docker run --no-healthcheck --name kms -p 8888:8888 -d kurento/kurento-media-server`